# How would uncontrolled zombies react to a zombie raised by a necromancer?

Tags: dnd-5e, undead, necromancy

If a necromancer raises a zombie, then orders the zombie to cross into area containing non-controlled zombies, how would the non-controlled zombies react?  I've always assumed 'wild' undead don't destroy one another, but is there a reason for that?

I'm asking about D&D 5e, but I'd be interested if any edition of D&D commented on this.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Take the [tour] if you haven't already, and check out the [help] for more guidance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

### Uncontrolled [zombies](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/zombie) act how they like

Which is to say, they act the way the DM wants them to act.

As for what is written in the Monster Manual, it could go either way.

> A zombie left without orders simply stands in place and rots until something comes along that it can kill.

Suggests it will attack.

> ... left without a purpose, it attacks any living creature it encounters.

Suggests it might not attack undead.

> ... can distinguish friends from foes ...

Suggests it may be able to make up its mind if the new zombie is friend or foe subject to the limits that it’s really stupid.